# How to find the Big O when there are two separate for loops

Tags: c, for-loop, big-o

I know how to find Big O for "for loops" and nested "for loops", but what happens when we have two for loops, not nested but two separate for loops in the same function.

Comment: For two separate `for` loops with iteration `n` an `m` where `n > m`, order would be `O(n)`.

Comment: @haccks : How to know if n  > m ?

Comment: You don't know. You just assume that n is bigger. The whole notation is about approximating the programs complexity. If you want to be more precise you can do it like @cruxioneffux shows in the answer.

Comment: @user3928326 If you loop through an `n`-size array, it's `O(n)`. e.g. `for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)` is obviously `O(n)`.

Comment: I've just found a quite nice summary of the big-O complexities. http://bigocheatsheet.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It just gets added.

See for e.g. :

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    //statements

for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    //statements
```

So the total complexity is O(m+n).

lets say m=3n then 
its O(4n) which is O(n) only .

let m = n^2

then its O(n^2+n) which is O(n^2)